# SQL query to join 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, join

I want to join the following 2 tables in postgres:

```
table1 (
   i1 character varying
 , i2 character varying
 , i3 character varying
)  

table2 (
   i4 character varying
 , startorend character varying
 , begin integer
 , end character integer
)
```

table1 contains the following values:

```
  p1  p2    p3
  p4  p10   p6
  p7  p8    p9
  p99 p199  p299
```

table2 contains the following values:

```
  p4  begin 1   12
  p4  end   13  14
  p7  begin 19  20
  p1  end   21  22
```

Now I want to join the 2 tables, such that the below mentioned rules are obeyed:

```
1. When table1.i1=table2.i4, then 
   1a. If there are 2 rows containing begin and end corresponding to table2,
       then choose table2.begin and table2.end
       from the begin and end columns respectively from table2.i4.  
   1b. If there is only 1 row containing begin or end corresponding to table2,
       then assume and write the default value as end(9999) and begin(0).
```

By applying the above rules, I get the below mentioned table:

```
p4      1            14
p1      0(default)   22 (as it just contains end column in table 2, therefore 0(begin) as default is inserted)
p7      19           9999(default) (as it just contains begin column in table2, therefore 9999(end) as default is inserted)
```

I can efficiently join the tables, but us it possible to insert the default values by any chance?

Comment: So table1 doesn't have anything to do with the logic you're mentioning. Am I right? Is it possible to assume only `begin` or `end`  are allowed in the `beginorend` column? Can there be more than 2 records of a given `i4` value?

Comment: @table1 is important there is a join in table1.i1=table2.i4

Comment: It seems the begin and end values for `startorend = 'begin'` are always less than the same values for `startorend = 'end'`. Also, it seems that for a given record all numbers in the begin column are less than all numbers in the end column. Are those assumptions correct? Please, be clear in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT i4
      ,CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 OR min(startorend) = 'begin' THEN min("begin")
            ELSE 0 END AS the_begin
      ,CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 OR min(startorend) = 'end'   THEN min("end")
            ELSE 9999 END AS the_end
FROM   table2 t2
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.i1 = t2.i4)
GROUP  BY i4
```

*Assuming* that `table1.i1` is `UNIQUE` or it only matters that one or more matching rows exist.

`begin` and `end` are [reserved words in the SQL standard](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html). You shouldn't use them as identifiers. That's why I double-quoted.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it by creating nested selects for begin and end values, doing an outer join, then using ISNULL to substitute default values when no matching rows are found.

```
SELECT Table1.i1, 
       ISNULL(BeginValues.begin, 0), 
       ISNULL(EndValues.end, 9999)
FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT i4, begin 
         FROM Table2 
         WHERE Table2.startorend = 'begin') AS BeginValues 
        ON Table1.i1 = BeginValues.i4 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT i4, end 
         FROM Table2 
         WHERE Table2.startorend = 'end') AS EndValues 
        ON Table1.i1 = EndValues.i4
```